# php - PayPal Express Checkout Item name and number

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-adaptive-payments

Why isn't the item name and number not being submitted with the DoExpressCheckout?

Here is what I am sending:

```
// Single-item purchase
$nvps["METHOD"] = "SetExpressCheckout";
$nvps["RETURNURL"] = "http://www.domain.com/angelpaypal/test/success.php"; // server
$nvps["CANCELURL"] = "http://www.domain.com/angelpaypal/test/fail.php"; // server
$nvps["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION"] = "Sale";
$nvps["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NOTIFYURL"] = "http://www.domain.com/includes/ipn/paypal/config/ipn-listener.php";
$nvps["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT"] = "$Price";
$nvps["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE"] = "USD";
$nvps["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT"] = "$Price";
$nvps["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0"] = "$Desc";
$nvps["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0"] = "$Item";
$nvps["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0"] = "$Price";
$nvps["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0"] = "1";
$nvps["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMCATEGORY0"] = "Digital"; // specific to Digital Goods
```

Below is the response:

```
TOKEN = EC-7RN61912TS2838617
SUCCESSPAGEREDIRECTREQUESTED = false
TIMESTAMP = 2014-03-07T19:16:39Z
CORRELATIONID = b65c4f8669542
ACK = Success
VERSION = 109.0
BUILD = 9917844
INSURANCEOPTIONSELECTED = false
SHIPPINGOPTIONISDEFAULT = false
PAYMENTINFO_0_TRANSACTIONID = 3PF8162359151561E
PAYMENTINFO_0_TRANSACTIONTYPE = expresscheckout
PAYMENTINFO_0_PAYMENTTYPE = instant
PAYMENTINFO_0_ORDERTIME = 2014-03-07T19:16:39Z
PAYMENTINFO_0_AMT = 5.00
PAYMENTINFO_0_FEEAMT = 0.45
PAYMENTINFO_0_TAXAMT = 0.00
PAYMENTINFO_0_CURRENCYCODE = USD
PAYMENTINFO_0_PAYMENTSTATUS = Completed
PAYMENTINFO_0_PENDINGREASON = None
PAYMENTINFO_0_REASONCODE = None
PAYMENTINFO_0_PROTECTIONELIGIBILITY = Ineligible
PAYMENTINFO_0_PROTECTIONELIGIBILITYTYPE = None
PAYMENTINFO_0_SECUREMERCHANTACCOUNTID = KEPBS3TF5VPSL
PAYMENTINFO_0_ERRORCODE = 0
PAYMENTINFO_0_ACK = Success
```

As yuo can see, I am specifying item name and number, although in the response above, I don't see these fields - **I want to use them in the IPN (NOTIFYURL) I've added**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've shown here is SetExpressCheckout.  Setting the items here will only make them show up on the PayPal review page during checkout.  It will not carry all the way through to the final transaction unless you include those same itemizes details in the DoExpressCheckoutPayment request.

DECP is the end all, be all.  Whatever gets sent with that is what ends up in the final PayPal details.